# Trigger not checking if condition

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

I have created a trigger , and this trigger updating the field value , but not checking the if condition ,

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger `njsystem`.`test` BEFORE UPDATE on `njsystem`.`tbl_users` 
for each row 
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.user_failed_logins > 3) THEN
        UPDATE tbl_users SET user_active = 0;
    END IF;
END; $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your problem statement is that, you wanted to set user_active to 0 if  user_failed_logins count goes above 3. Here is solution for that, you can also change values using new.

```
DELIMITER $$
create trigger `test` BEFORE UPDATE on `tbl_users` 
for each row 
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.user_failed_logins > 3) THEN
        SET NEW.user_active = 0;
    END IF;
END; $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: now I have used the above code , but its still updating the user_active = 0 , either user_failed_logins is greater than 3 or less then . 
every time trigger hitting , its updating the value of user_active = 0.